# Multiple GRUB installs with UEFI: how do they find their config?

Tags: grub2, uefi

According to Rod Smith's UEFI docs at http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/grub2.html, grub.cfg can either be installed alongside grubx64.efi on the EFI partition, or left in /boot/ on a linux partition. Apparently, Ubuntu uses the latter method.

My question is: how does GRUB find *the* Linux partition if there are more of them? Is grubx64.efi a custom build for every install, containing a partition UUID? Is there a search order for Linux partitions?

What I'm looking for specifically: is it possible to set up multiple GRUB installs on the UEFI level, with e.g. two grubx64.efi files, each using a different GRUB config file?

(My specific use case is installing Ubuntu alongside SteamOS which already has GRUB installed, with the least amount of changes possible.)

Comment: With Ubuntu I have not had any sucess with multiple grub installs. The standard grub2 with Ubuntu is hard coded to find a /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg and that is a configfile to the actual install. And I tried renaming installs with GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR= to a different name and it adds a new entry to UEFI. But only boots the same install. You just use grub menu to choose other installs. There must be a configuration parameter somewhere as other installs do use /EFI/grub or other names.

Comment: ... so GRUB really doesn't look like it was designed with multiple installs in mind then... quite useful experience, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The location of GRUB's configuration file is hard-coded in the `grubx64.efi` binary. The last I checked, Ubuntu worked in one of two ways, depending on which package you installed:

- If you install the Secure Boot-capable version of GRUB, it looks in `EFI/ubuntu` on the same volume as the GRUB binary for `grub.cfg`. This file is then customized to point back to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, referring to the partition by UUID number.
- If you install the *non*-Secure-Boot version of GRUB, the package modifies the `grubx64.efi` binary at install time so that it refers directly to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Note that it's been a while since I checked these details, and I never delved into them all that deeply, so I may be mistaken about some of this.

The upshot of this is that, if you want to use two GRUBs that point to two different configuration files, you must modify the `grubx64.efi` binary yourself. There's an [old Ubuntu wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting) that describes how to build GRUB for EFI. This page is mostly outdated, and in fact points to another page as a replacement; but the new page doesn't describe the "nuts and bolts" of building a GRUB binary. It's been a while since I reviewed the old page in any depth, so I can't promise it will tell you what you need to know, but it may.

IMHO, this is all too much effort. ELILO, SYSLINUX, and rEFInd all use configuration files in their home directories, so you can install a dozen of each (in separate directories) and each of them will have its own configuration file. These programs' configuration files are all also much easier to maintain than is GRUB 2's -- although if you're doing it by hand, GRUB 2 needn't be all that much worse than others.

For your specific case, you might find a single rEFInd installation to be the best option. It auto-detects kernels on each boot, so one rEFInd installation will handle both your distributions with no need for extra configuration when you update a kernel. (You may need to set up a `/boot/refind_linux.conf` file in each distribution to handle distribution-specific kernel options, though.) Caveat: I'm rEFInd's maintainer, so I'm not exactly unbiased.

Comment: awesome, thanks for the detailed answer! (will try rEFInd most likely as a next step :))