# 3 OSs: Win10 and Ubuntu14.04 on drive sda and Ubuntu 16.04 on sdb

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a UEFI laptop with Windows10 and Ubuntu 14.04 in dual boot on the original ssd drive /dev/sda.

I want to add a new ssd drive /dev/sdb and install Ubuntu16.04 without changing any configuration on /dev/sda.

Indeed my goal is to first select witch HDD to boot throught uefi menu and then select the OS in grub.

So in this way I will have two different grubs. The first one on /dev/sda will show the same options as today:
- Ubuntu14.04
- Windows10
while the second one (on /dev/sdb) will show only Ubuntu 16.04.

Is this configuration feasible?
SHould I disable /dev/sda before starting the Ubuntu 16.04 installatin?
Is there the risk of damaging /dev/sda?

Comment: I have tried many times. Grub only wants to install to drive seen as sda with UEFI. Or second install overwrites /EFI/ubuntu folder. I quickly learned to backup entire ESP. The only time I did get it to install to "sdb" was when it really was sda, by disconnecting sda. But then UEFI forgot all UEFI entries from sda's ESP, so I had to use efibootmgr to recreate those entries. I have given up. And just use ESP on sdb as backup of ESP on sda. Which in an emergency I could get to work to boot install on sdb. Note Fedora let me install grub directly to sdb, not sure why Ubuntu cannot?

Comment: @oldfred for the clarification. So the only solution seems to let grub modify /dev/sda during the installation of Ubuntu 16.04 on /dev/sdb.

Is it possible that this procedure will screw up /dev/sda? So preventing boot of Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Each install changes the /EFI/ubuntu with most current installs info. See your /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg. It has UUID & partition info. I learned I just need to edit that back to UUID & partition of my main working install or I separately back up grub.cfg 3 line configfile file.User posted example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/958760/what-does-gpt7-refers-to-in-my-grub-cfg see also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/721970/multiple-grub-installs-with-uefi-how-do-they-find-their-config

Comment: Please [edit] this question to fix typos such as `throught`, `witch`, `SHould`, and `installatin`.